# SyntaxError with custom function using QgsFeatureRequest.setFilterExpression

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, string, syntax

```
def get_subsel(layer,filter):
    layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    for lyr in layers:
        if lyr.name() == layer:
            request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(filter)

            iter = lyr.getFeatures(request)
            ids = [i.id() for i in iter]
            lyr.setSelectedFeatures(ids)

            selected_feats = lyr.selectedFeatures()

    new_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:277000", "acc_subselection", "memory")
    data_prov = new_layer.dataProvider()
    data_prov.addFeatures(selected_feats)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry().instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
```

I'm trying to use the code above with filter = `("\"accdate\" >= '1990-01-01' AND \"accdate\" <= '1992-12-31'")`. If I type this in to the python console line for line (i.e. without using the function) it works fine. But typing the filter as defined above in to the function I get an error in the first line (so the code hasn't executed yet):

`get_subsel("accident", "("\"accdate\" >= '1990-01-01' AND \"accdate\" <= '1992-12-31'")` `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` with the `^` pointing at '1990-01-**0**1' (where **bold**).

It looks like it's getting confused with the `\` escape-character...but like I said it works when typed in to the console. I'm more experienced in MapBasic programming (MapInfo GIS), where I would build `filter` by concatenating strings and e.g. `CHR$(34)` or `CHR$(92)`, which at runtime are interpreted as `"` and `\`, respectively. Hopefully that's clear enough

So do I need to do something similar in order for python to interpret the various quotes and backslashes correctly at runtime?

the layer is from a Postgres database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your escaping isn't write quite right. It should be:

```
(\"accdate\" >= '1990-01-01' AND \"accdate\" <= '1992-12-31')
```

(You have some extra "s)

Also note that:

```
iter = lyr.getFeatures(request)
ids = [i.id() for i in iter]
lyr.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
selected_feats = lyr.selectedFeatures()
```

Is quite inefficient. Try:

```
iter = lyr.getFeatures(request)
selected_feats = [f for f in iter]
```

instead

Comment: have only just got round to actually trying this. I've now used the function like this `get_subsel("accident", "\"accdate\" >= '1990-01-01' AND \"accdate\" <= '1992-12-31'")` and it appears to work. well, i have a different error but unrelated

Comment: improved comment above, but after the 5 minute edit-window: have only just got round to actually trying this. maybe I misunderstood your instructions, I got pretty much the same error putting the filter-string in (without brackets) as you suggested. but I've now used the function like this `get_subsel("accident", "\"accdate\" >= '1990-01-01' AND \"accdate\" <= '1992-12-31'")` and it appears to work. well, i have a different error but unrelated